# Function within route handler

Tags: node.js, express

**In an Express route handler, is there a way to have a function that moves execution to the next middleware function as follows?**

```js
const myRouteHandler = (req,res,next) => {

    const user = getUserFromDb();

    stuffThatMultipleHandlersUse(user, next);

    // Only do this stuff, if the above function did not return
    return res....
}

const stuffThatMultipleHandlersUse(user, next) {
    if(!user.something) {
        return next(new AppError(...));
    }
}
```

Basically, I am trying to take bits of functionality that is used in multiple route handlers and move that functionality into its own functions to keep my route handlers short and DRY.

But the problem with the above is that even if `return next(new AppError(...));` is triggered in the function, then `return res....` will still be executed in the route handler. How can I address this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this code below:

```js
const myRouteHandler = (req,res,next) => {

  const user = getUserFromDb();

  stuffThatMultipleHandlersUse(user).then(result => {
    return res...
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}

const stuffThatMultipleHandlersUse(user) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(!user.something) reject(new AppError(...));
    resolve(user);
  })
}
```

I hope it's work.